# Visual Studio 2015 shortens automatically added usings / Imports

Tags: visual-studio-2015, using

The behavior of automatically adding `using` (or `Import` for the VB people) directives at the top of the file has changed in VS2015, compared to VS2013. Hence the following code:

```cs
namespace CommanderKeen.Enemies
{
    class Dopefish
    {
    }
}

namespace CommanderKeen
{
    using System;

    class GameLogic
    {
        public GameLogic()
        {
            // I reference the Dopefish class, being in another sub-namespace here,
            // and want VS to automatically import this namespace.
            Dopefish neverDies = new Dopefish();
        }
    }
}
```

In **VS2013**, the following line would be added after the `using System;` directive:

```cs
using CommanderKeen.Enemies;
```

E.g., the fully qualified namespace. **VS2015** however shortens this to just:

```cs
using Enemies;
```

...due to the case my `using` directives are all placed inside the namespace. However, I never saw that this is common practice, even with `using` directives placed in this (less common) way.

I can fix this by moving my `using` directives outside of the `namespace` scope, but I don't really want to do that, as my whole projects are organized like this by now.

Does anyone know if this is fixable, possibly through an add-on?

Comment: It is just a little innocent light-bulb, you don't *have* to click it just because it is there.  Mind over machine.

Comment: Of course, but I use this feature so much, it has become standard to me to simply smash Alt+Shift+F10+Enter to add a using. Scrolling back to my using part and adding it there manually is just tedious.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I changed my coding standards to put the using directives in front of the namespace region again, since we only have one namespace per file anyway...

Comment: @HansPassant - It's the defacto way that using statements get added to code; nobody in my team nor anybody else I know manually types out using statements. I know I haven't for years. Why isn't there an option in the 'coding style' settings to control this? It's really frustrating to see usings so cluttered and inconsistent.

Comment: I've tried to manually edit the installed code analysis rulesets (the ones that ship with VS) - it disables the 'greying out' of the code, but it does not change the behavior of the lightbulb - namespaces are still added, shortened.

Comment: The way you are including  using directives to your files is pretty uncommon to me. I always keep using directives outside the rest of the namespace. You could also try to use Resharper from the Jetbrains for adding using directives, at least the demo version to see if it's what you need.

Comment: @meJustAndrew: Yes, it was indeed an uncommon way I used. I liked it because it encapsulated the usings inside the namespace, giving an advantage of having different usings if you ever have multiple namespaces in one file. In the end, since that's just bad practice, and since VS messed this up quite a little, I got rid of that by now and put them outside of the namespace again, even if it does not have such a nice encapsulation anymore.